# How come I can not use android.util.Base64?

Tags: android, base64

```
The import android.util.Base64 cannot be resolved
```

is Base64 class really inside the util package? Need some help! 
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`android.util.Base64` has been included since Android API Level 8 (i.e. Android 2.2.x or later)

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

For older version, you have to download the library or source code manually and put it under your project.

Comment: Thank you Victor! Where can I download the source code? The link just links to the documentation.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/util/Base64.java

Comment: where will I find old code? above link is not working.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html